# Bootstrap: what's semantically the most appropriate style for submit buttons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Recently the [official Bootstrap documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/) has finally given clear specifications about the **semantic** purpose of their button styles:

> **Primary** Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons
>
> **Success** Indicates a successful or positive action
>
> **Danger** Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action

I've written a RAD framework for rapid creation of web forms. It's based on Bootstrap and it's used by third parties on different websites, each one with its own custom color scheme / variation, on which the corresponding colours won't necessarily be blue and green, but vary to reflect the style of the website or the meaning of the colours in the culture of the target users.

Having to determine the bootstrap style to assign to the form buttons, I can't base my choice on their predefined colours, but on the style meaning instead.

The choice is simple for the reset button for which the "danger" style seems perfect.

```
class="btn btn-danger"
```

But what about the submit button? Which one between "primary" and "success" is **semantically** the most appropriate for the submit button of a web form?

Comment: If it's a positive action e.g. create or update something I prefer success. If it's a button for report a user I prefer warning and if the button deletes something I use danger

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter really, it's a question of taste, but I'd say 'Success' is better suited to the 'Submit' or 'Complete' action - while 'Primary' suggests it triggers the primary action - 'Print' or 'Next' for example. Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

success is the best because green means carry on. and primary is generally used for okay button. hope you find your answer.

Answer (score -1):

It all depends on your website theme/color combination. To me, they are just blue and green buttons.

If your website has color like Facebook then you should probably go for a primary that gels with the website theme color. But if the colors of your website are like Google+ then probably a bootstrap danger button will be more appropriate.

If you want to highlight a button then choose a color accordingly​, like I'll choose a warning button to highlight an action if I am using primary elsewhere.

They are just colored buttons, don't think of them in terms of success or danger or whatever​. Hope that helps.

Comment: I disagree. If they were just colored buttons, they'd be named btn-green, btn-blue and etc. OP is talking about semantics.